# Where is the Numlock key on this ridiculous keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, numlock

I am using Windows 8 (or 8.1) and I need the NumLock key so I can enter Alt codes. But the problem is that there isn't even a NumLock key, even though I looked at the keyboard.

This is a Samsung laptop and the model is `700T Notebook XE700T1C`.
Here is an image of my keyboard:

[image: One half of my Keyboard]

[image: Other half of my Keyboard]

Comment: Your image is too grainy to see anything. It would help to have both a clear image of your keyboard and the make/model of your laptop.

Comment: Then should i label each key using an editor?

Comment: No, you should provide a clear photo and the make and model of your laptop. [edit] your post to fix it.

Comment: Nice try on the photos.  Let me be specific: some keys we can see the white.  But Caps Lock looks blurry, and most importantly, the non-white labels seem impossible to see.  A close-up, with camera still, sufficiently high resolution is believed to be more helpful.  I did an image search for Samsung 700T Notebook XE700T1C.  Did not find great images of the same keyboard.  But it looks like this keyboard might be removable/bluetooth, and that there may be other options.  (Not as clear whether any of those are better.)  Using Fn, kind of like how Alt is used, has become common.

Comment: @Phoenix You don't have a keyboard with a purpose for `NumLock`... `NumLock` is usually only on laptops that have a full keyboard with the extra number keys.  I'm assuming your asking because your number keys also have functions tied to each and those functionas are likely the keys' default behavioir... this can be disabled either via the `FN Lock` key or via an option in the BIOS/UEFI Firmware

Comment: All the images I found on the net of this or similar keyboards indicate it does not have a “numpad area” that could be toggled. Without one, Alt codes cannot be entered. Your best bet is most likely to just use a different keyboard.

Comment: @JW0914 yes but certain keyboard without a numpad has a key that can function as a Numlock key (e.g a FN key can be used to activate Numlock)

Comment: @Phoenix Right, but without a Numpad, the `NumLock` key has no purpose _(your keyboard has a `FN Lock` key)_... the purpose of the `NumLock` key is to toggle between the numerals on the NumPad and the functions those keys can also perform... _it serves no other purpose_. Without a Numpad, your laptop has no purpose for the `NumLock` key, ergo it doesn't come one; Instead, your laptop, like almost all laptops with/without a Numpad, has a `FN Lock` key to toggle between the keyboard's numerals and functions _(it's located above `+`/`=`)_, so there's likely another combo to enter ALT codes.

Comment: @Phoenix (cont'd) You'll likely be able to find what additional key needs to be activated for ALT codes either in the laptop's manual, the OEM's support site, or the OEM's tech support.  It may be `FN`+`ALT`, or a variance of, but since ALT codes are standardized, it's unlikely the OEM didn't create a way to use them.  I would first try the laptop method of enabling `FN Lock`, then using the `M`, `L`, `K`, `J`, `O`, `I`, `U`, `7`, `8`, `9`  keys to enter the ALT code _(`M` - `U` are `0` - `6` when `FN Lock` is enabled)_.  If this works, I'll create an answer with reference links.

Comment: `FN`+`ALT` does not work. The reason for the numlock is to enter alt codes. Also there is an `ALT GR` key that works with us international, but it doesn't have the symbol I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a shortcut on the desktop to toggle NumLock on and off.

Create a `.vbs` file containing the following text:

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
```

[Create a shortcut icon](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182161-shortcut-create-file-folder-drive-program-windows.html)
for the script on the desktop.

You may now double-click the icon to toggle the NumLock state.

You may also right-click the icon and choose
`Properties` to assign it a shortcut key.

Comment: Great answer, but what would this accomplish on a keyboard without the extra number keys, which is what `NumLock` is used to toggle?

Comment: @JW0914: I assume that the user needs it for some application.

Comment: Yes, but the question **is** whether there is a NumLock key for this keyboard.

Comment: @Phoenix: Physically the NumLock key is not needed for this keyboard, since there is no NumPad. NumLock for this keyboard creates a keyboard-state that is remembered by Windows and can be consulted by applications, although it has no effect on keyboard keys because the keys that could be affected are not there. An external NumPad can be bought and connected if required.

Comment: It is to enter alt codes. Also I do not want to buy a Numpad.

Comment: You may get a virtual one by selecting in the Start menu the "On-Screen Keyboard".  You can also create an icon for it by right-click on the above icon or by using the executable name - `osk.exe`.

Comment: Ok, now let me point out some problems althought this is a bit late. The alt button will only accept one button to be pressed. E.G If I enter ```ALT```+```255```, it will do nothing. However if I press it once, then enter a number, then it will toggle off. It will not communicate properly with the actual keyboard so even if I press ```ALT```, and enter ```255``` on the numpad in the onscreen keyboard, it will do nothing.

Comment: Remark: The code for me is Alt+0255. Yes, I discovered also that it's impossible to use the OSK for it, since there is no way to hold the Alt down. I found a replacement: [numpad emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpad-emulator/files/). You need to click the Options symbol to "Add/Remove buttons", then drag the Alt key to its place. Now you can click Alt down, click 0255, then click Alt again to unpress it.

Answer (score 0):

The pictures too unclean to really tell from the looks of it but not all keyboards have every key

You can enable num lock on windows virtual keyboard, there is software to map custom short cuts to any windows key, but im not allowed to recommend software in an answer..

> Windows + Ctrl + O is the hot key in Windows 10 for faster access.

**Windows 10**

1. Right-click the Windows icon, select Settings > Ease of Access >
   Keyboard, and then move the slider under On-Screen Keyboard.
2. A keyboard appears on the screen. Click Options and check Turn on
   numeric keypad, then click OK.

**Windows 8/8.1**

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
2. Enter On-Screen Keyboard in the search box, and then tap or click
   On-Screen Keyboard. Click Options and check Turn on numeric keypad.
   Click OK.

**Windows 7**

1. Open On-Screen Keyboard by clicking the Start button, All Programs,
   Accessories, Ease of Access, and then On-Screen Keyboard.
2. A keyboard appears on the screen, click Options and check Turn on
   numeric keypad, and then click OK.

Comment: The thing is that it is really annoying to have to go through search to launch it. That why i was asking whether there was even a Numlock key.

Comment: Windows + Ctrl + O is the hotkey on windows 10 to make it a little faster

Comment: That shortcut is an open shortcut on window 8 or 8.1

Comment: This is for window 8 or 8.1, but I guess it would be useful for windows 10